# Serialize C# object using JSON.NET for Dojo data-dojo-props

Tags: dojo, json.net

Dojo's `dijit` html5 tags use an attribte name data-dojo-props.  The value is basically a JSON string without quotes around the property names and without the outermost braces.

It looks something like this.

```
data-dojo-props="prop1:'xyz', prop2:true, prop3: { subprop1: 1, subprop2: 'abc'}"
```

I'm using C# to write this out from a C# object using JSON.NET and passing in the object pointer.  I found settings to leave out the property name quotes, but I can't figure out a graceful way to remove the outside braces.

For now, I'll run the string through a regex to remove them, but was wondering if someone new a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I serialize each top level property separately and make it a global javascript variable.  I then reference that variable in `data-dojo-props`.  I admit it's not that elegant.

My concern with your approach above, is if the value of `subprop2` contains a quote, you will get a parser error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    menuData = {THE SERIALIZED JSON GOES HERE};
</script>
<div data-dojo-type="SomeWidget" data-dojo-props="menuData: menuData"></div>
```

Comment: Well, actually, JSON.net will make those single quotes @quot; so that's not a problem.  Also, you're allowed to have single quotes since the entire attribute value is enclosed in double quotes.  They way my code is structured, I really need to keep the global variable down to a minimum, so I prefer embedding the properties in the html and not have a separate js variable.  Thanks for the suggestion though.